# Reading a string from one file and comparing it with another file and giving alarm if condition met

Tags: linux, string, bash, shell, for-loop

I have `2` files  `File1, and File2`. `File1` is list of `strings`,   `line1 contain string1`, `line2 contains strings2 and so on`. I would like to pick `string1` from `File1` and compare it with `File 2`. Then I pick `string2` and compare it with `File2`. The script does not know how many strings are there in `File1 and Fil2`. Once all the strings from `File1 are compared with File2,` the script should give an `alarm/pop up window` with the list of `strings` matched in `File2`.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution in bash? or any programming lang. is fine?

Comment: satvik choudhary, yes bash linux. could you please guide me

Comment: Does it have to be `for` loop (or any loop) specifically? Because what you are asking for is a set intersection, i.e., lines that are both in `File1` and `File2`. This can be done using a single `grep` or `sort` or couple others.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Divide and conquer. Start with the loop reading `File1` and then add the other stuff.

Comment: danadam, it can be any loop for any number of strings. The important is, once strings are matched in File2, it should give a pop up window or alarm with list of matched strings.

Comment: @HatLess, thanks but sorry I have no clue how to do it

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano, thanks could you please elaborate a bit with a simple example? thanks

Comment: Leave alarm/pop up, etc. alone and concentrate on the loop and match. Then move on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what you mean by popup/window.
Also it will be better to use something like grep.
Based on the requirement, this is what I came up with.

```
// abc.txt
abcd
ab
cd
abc

// def.txt
dfd
abc
ab
abcd



file1=()
file2=()

filename1="abc.txt"
filename2="def.txt"
while read -r line; do
    name="$line"
    file1+=("$name")
done < "$filename1"

while read -r line; do
    name="$line"
    file2+=("$name")
done < "$filename2"

for i in "${file2[@]}"
do
   for j in "${file1[@]}"
   do
      if [ "$i" = "$j" ]; then
         echo "Match found $i"
         break
      fi
   done
done
```

Comment: @sarvik .about pop up window meaning once script has run through i should get an alaram with list of matched strings. how i can get an alarm after the script has run?

Comment: In Ubuntu  replacing     echo "Match found $i"         with               notify-send "$i"    will you give you nice desktop notification. Don't know this is what you mean by alarm.

Comment: does your code gives list of all matched strings or prints after each match?

Comment: prints after each match. you can add to a list like this.        list+=($i) instead of echo "Match found $i"